# Empty CELERY_ROUTES setting in celery worker

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

The `CELERY_ROUTES` configuration setting seems to be ignored by the celery workers, but other settings (from the same config file) are not.  As can be seen below, running
`app.control.inspect().conf()` shows an empty CELERY_ROUTES setting, yet all other customized settings in the config file match in the output of `app.control.inspect().conf()`.

Contents of celeryconfig.py:

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle']
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
CELERY_ROUTES = { 'psync.sync_hardlink':   {'queue': 'hardlinks'}, }
```

The `celeryconfig.py` settings are read in using:

```
import celeryconfig
app.conf.update( **{ k:getattr( celeryconfig,k ) for k in dir( celeryconfig ) if not k.startswith('__') } )
```

Note: I am explicitly not using the `config_from_object()` method since I am reading in config settings from several files and `config_from_object()` overwrites previously set options so is only useful once.

I check config settings from an external script, as follows:

```
import psync #this is my library defining `app` and celery tasks
i = psync.app.control.inspect()
pprint.pprint( i.conf() )
```

After the worker is started, running the external script outputs:

```
{u'psync_worker@ie05': {u'BROKER_URL': u'amqp://username:********@10.10.108.4:5672/PSYNCVHOST',
                        u'CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL': u'INFO',
                        u'CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER': 1,
                        u'CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT': [u'pickle'],
                        u'CELERY_INCLUDE': [u'celery.app.builtins', u'psync'],
                        u'CELERY_ROUTES': {}}}
```

As can be seen from the output, several settings have been changed from the default and match what is set in `celeryconfig.py` and it appears CELERY_ROUTES has been changed also, but it's empty.

Why would some celeryconfig settings be respected and others ignored?

Relevant versions:

```
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.20
celery==3.1.18
kombu==3.0.33
```